# How to delete several different data from Core Data in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have `Core Data` with five objects. It's four `String` and one `NSData` (`UIImage`). I save them in `Core Data`. Then load in `UIViewController` and I want to delete them from Core Data and I got different errors. I tried different methods but it doesn't helped me. How do I delete these data?

```
var name: String!
var text: String!
var image: UIImage!
var url: String!
var data: String!

    func deleteAll() {
    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    var coreDataName: NSManagedObject = (name as AnyObject?) as! NSManagedObject
    var coreDataImage: NSManagedObject = (image as AnyObject?) as! NSManagedObject
    var coreDataText: NSManagedObject = (text as AnyObject?) as! NSManagedObject
    var coreDataData: NSManagedObject = (data as AnyObject?) as! NSManagedObject
    var coreDataURL: NSManagedObject = (url as AnyObject?) as! NSManagedObject

    managedObjectContext.deleteObject(coreDataName)
    managedObjectContext.deleteObject(coreDataImage)
    managedObjectContext.deleteObject(coreDataText)
    managedObjectContext.deleteObject(coreDataData)
    managedObjectContext.deleteObject(coreDataURL)
    managedObjectContext.save(nil)

    buttonDelete.enabled = false
    buttonShare.enabled = false
}

}
```

My `Core Data` file

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(News)

    class News: NSManagedObject {

        @NSManaged var dateNewsCoreDataString: String
        @NSManaged var imageNewsCoreData: NSData // NSData
        @NSManaged var nameNewsCoreData: String
        @NSManaged var textNewsCoreData: String
        @NSManaged var urlNewsCoreData: String 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code and it work for me.

```
 var detailObject: AnyObject? // It's data from FavoriteTableViewController

    func deleteAll() {
        var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        var dataDelete = detailObject as! NSManagedObject

        managedObjectContext.deleteObject(dataDelete)
        managedObjectContext.save(nil)

        managedObjectContext.save(nil)
        buttonDelete.enabled = false
        buttonShare.enabled = false
    }
```